# Get data between dates and null

Tags: mysql, date, join

I have to get the right data of a customer, which could be outdated respectively not the latest data.

Tables:

```
Customer
+---------------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+
| Field                     | Type          | Null | Key | Default |
+---------------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+
| customer_id               | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    |
| customer_data             | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |
| customer_valid_from       | datetime      | NO   |     | NULL    |
| customer_valid_till       | datetime      | YES  |     | NULL    |
+---------------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+

Address
+---------------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+
| Field                     | Type          | Null | Key | Default |
+---------------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+
| address_id                | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    |
| address_street            | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |
| address_valid_from        | datetime      | NO   |     | NULL    |
| address_valid_till        | datetime      | YES  |     | NULL    |
| customer_id               | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL    |
+---------------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+

Details
+---------------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+
| Field                     | Type          | Null | Key | Default |
+---------------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+
| detail_id                 | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    |
| detail_street             | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |
| detail_valid_from         | datetime      | NO   |     | NULL    |
| detail_valid_till         | datetime      | YES  |     | NULL    |
| customer_id               | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL    |
+---------------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+
```

At the beginning i got a date and customer_id.
Now i want to select all data, which concerns the customer with the given customer_id at the date, which is also given.

My SQL at the moment looks like this:

```
SELECT customer.*,address.*,details.*
FROM customer
JOIN address
ON address.customer_id = customer.customer_id
JOIN details
ON details.customer.customer_id = customer.customer.id
WHERE customer.customer_valid_from <= givenDate
AND customer.customer_valid_till >= givenDate
AND address.address_valid_from <= givenDate
AND address.address_valid_till >= givenDate
AND details.details_valid_from <= givenDate
AND details.details_valid_till >= givenDate
customer.customer_id = givenID;
```

In my view there is a part missing.
What if a record matches the valid_from <= givenDate but has a valid_till, which is NULL or "0000-00-00 00:00:00"?

I thought about an IF or CASE-clause, but my experience with MySQL is unsatisfactory .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this `from` clause:

```
WHERE customer.customer_valid_from <= givenDate AND
      (customer.customer_valid_till >= givenDate OR
       customer.customer_valid_till IS NULL OR
       customer.customer_valid_till  = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
      ) AND
      address.address_valid_from <= givenDate AND
      (address.address_valid_till >= givenDate OR
       address.address_valid_till IS NULL OR
       address.address_valid_till = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
      ) AND
      details.details_valid_from <= givenDate AND
      (details.details_valid_till >= givenDate OR
       details.details_valid_till IS NULL OR
       details.details_valid_till = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
      )
```

It just adds the logic that you seem to be asking for.

Comment: Great! So the part in brackets is the IF-clause?

Comment: @Pero . . . The part in parentheses implements the logic that the `till` date can meet any of the three conditions.  `WHERE` is not exactly the same as `IF`; `WHERE` is filtering the data, row-by-row.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT customer.*,address.*,details.*
FROM customer
JOIN address
ON address.customer_id = customer.customer_id
JOIN details
ON details.customer.customer_id = customer.customer.id
WHERE customer.customer_valid_from <= givenDate
AND customer.customer_valid_till >= givenDate
AND address.address_valid_from <= givenDate
AND address.address_valid_till >= givenDate
AND details.details_valid_from <= givenDate
AND (details.details_valid_till >= givenDate OR details.details_valid_till IS NULL OR details.details_valid_till = '0000-00-00 00:00:00')
customer.customer_id = givenID;
```